# Using WCF service to handle SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

In the interest of saving time, I wrote a SQL module that allows me to write things in shorthand rather than having to initialise a `SqlCommand` object each time I wanted to run queries inside a module.

I'm now attempting to move this module over to a WCF service for security reasons (preventing Winforms app from directly accessing the database).

The following function is used to query the database and returns a `DataTable` of results

```
public DataTable FillTable(string sql)
{
    query = new SqlCommand();

    query.Connection = conn;
    query.CommandText = sql;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        dt.Load(query.ExecuteReader());
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        conn.Close();
        Console.Write("fillTable: " + ex.Message);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Given that this literally only takes a string as input, can I assume that this is open to potential injection attacks - despite it not being run directly on the database? If a potential attacker only knows the location of the service (based on the service reference within the application) could the submitted string be easily replaced and unauthorised data be extracted?

The database I'm working with is only small, but I want to make sure I do the security properly.

Naturally, I know I could write an individual function for each and every instance, but with nearly 100 uses within the project so far for that function alone, it would not only be a pain to do, but maintenance in the future would be a real headache

Comment: No much things to say. Yes your code is very vulnerable to any kind of Injection

Comment: you could have this as a private method and use it.  you need not expose this as a public web service.  in any case every api method has to have an authentication/ authorization check. whoever wants to use this service method has to do that .

Comment: Any particular reason you're still using plain SQL instead of switching to entity Framework and linq whom, by design, can not be affected by SQL injection?

Comment: @Steve that was my thought exactly. I think i already knew this, but didn't want to believe it.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau litterally the only reason is lack of experience with those frameworks.

Comment: When dealing with WCF, it is advisable *not* to use rather "heavy" objects like `DataTable` - instead, use a `List<T>` implementation that returns just the datatype needed (and no unnecessary overhead that the `DataTable` carries along)

Comment: @marc_s i've been lazy so far and, given that im going to rewrite a ton of code now, this would be a good time to do just that. Would it still be ok to use datatables when the data is being bound to a datagridview?

Comment: @Takarii: no - as I said - with WCF, you should *not* use `DataTable` and other .NET specific types, since WCF by its nature is very interoperable and should not have too many dependencies on .NET types (like `DataTable`), if ever possible

Comment: @marc_s interoperability hadn't even occured to me. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Takarii Then get experience, it will be faster to learn those than to rework your application and you'll realise that it removes all of the boilerplate code you have (for exemple everything in your function there would be replaced with well, Nothing at all if you used entity Framework)

Comment: @RonanThibaudau That's exactly what im going to do. Far too much needs rewriting.

Comment: @marc_s is it safe to assume that if there will only ever be a single result from the query, that you can return a single object rather than a list of objects, or should I return a list of 1?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, the code can be easily injected. A more secure way would be using Some ORM for this purpose. For example **Entity Framework** or **Hibernate**, they will help you deal with issues like SQL Injection etc.

OR

As said by @Fil you can **hide the implementation** from the user by wrapping it in some external method which you can expose to users.

Answer (score 1):

The server should be the only one to use this method FillTable. It hasvto be unreachable for the client.

Client should only kjow, for example, getBooks () and the server calls FillTable ("select * from books").

Comment: Thats what i was hoping i could avoid, but deep down i think i already knew it was the only real method